# Sharepoint 2010 Exchange Calendar overlay error

Tags: authentication, calendar, exchange-server

SharePoint Calendar gives that error below when using SharePoint Exchange Calendar overlay.

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,Basic realm="exchange.domain.com"'

We couldn't find any solution for this problem. Does anyone have any idea about the problem?

Comment: Are you using OWA URL when you're connecting the calendar in SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, i am writing additional information,
OWA URL: https://exchange.domain.com/owa/
Exchange Web Service URL: https://exchange.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to add the Root certificate in you SP Farm. Here are the steps to do it:

1) Go to "Central Administration" and click on "Security"

2) Under "General Security" click on "Manage trust"

3) Create a name (e.g. TestExchange)

4) Root certificate for the trust relationship:

5) Click OK

For more information on [how to add root certificate see this post](http://falakmahmood.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-add-root-certificate-as-trusting.html)

Comment: We already did this its not the solution.

Comment: Could you please check if Exchange OWA can be set up to use Basic or NTLM authentication. I would guess that SP is expecting NTLM, and Exchange is set to use Basic.